# VSCode Rename Refactor Preview Pane Doesn't Show

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When refactoring a variable in Flutter, a preview of the changes is helpful. However, the refactor preview panel (typically appears to the right of the Debug Console panel) won't show after pressing `F2` to rename and `Shift+Enter`. The settings are in place.

The screen below is after pressing `F2` to rename after the variable is highlighted:

[image]

The screen below is after pressing `Shift+Enter`:

[image]

Verified settings:

[image]
[image]

Changing the `Shift+Enter` keyboard shortcut to a shortcut not used at all like, `Alt+Shift+Enter`, didn't help either.

Any help is appreciated.